# SwiftUI: Weird auto scroll on TextField with axis .vertical

Tags: swiftui

I am currently building a draft generating / notes app that requires me to use SwiftUI's `TextField` with the axis set to `.vertical` so that the text field grows vertically when the text content grows.

However, when the TextField is placed inside `ScrollView`, the whole view gets auto-scrolled to the bottom of the view on focus with a janky animation. This seems to be caused by the resizing of the view due to keyboard avoidance but I cannot find a way to disable this unintended auto-scrolling behaviour.

Has anyone encountered this and if so, how were you able to solve it? Does UIKit alternative have the same issue?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Long text
    @State var longText: String = "Lorem ipsum dolor..."
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TextField("", text: $longText, axis: .vertical)
                .padding()
        }
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
    }
}
```

To solve this issue, I have tried placing the textfield inside LazyVStack or VStack, disabling safearea insets for keyboard but nothing seems to prevent the textfield / scrollview from auto scrolling when keyboard appears.